# Is there a simple but useful jquery.JsPlumb example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jsplumb

For the last week I've been searching for some graph-visualization javascript-library and I've stumbled upon [jsPlumb](http://jsplumb.org), which is judging by the examples I've seen, the best looking and most advanced library I've seen so far. The documentation is, while being quite big, not very helpful as I cannot figure out how to actually perform the most essential tasks.

My list of questions includes:

- How do I tell the graph to use predefined elements of the DOM-Tree?
- What part of these elements will be displayed?
- While making connections is easy, how do I define the alignment?

While these questions remain, there are a few examples, but either they are to simple to be of any use (see example 1), or they are so complex that even retrieving(well the download isn't a problem, but I don't really want to analyse everything before playing around with some library...) the code is at least for me impossible (see https://github.com/sporritt/jsPlumb/tree/master/demo).

Example 1

```
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
     src="PATH_TO/jquery.jsPlumb-1.3.15-all-min.js ">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     jsPlumb.bind("ready", function() {
        var e0 = jsPlumb.addEndpoint("container0"),
        e1 = jsPlumb.addEndpoint("container1");

        jsPlumb.connect({ source:e0, target:e1 });
     });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="container0">
   </div>
   <div id="container1">
   </div>
 </body>
```

Which results in
[image: Screenshot of Example 1]

Can anyone give me an Example which answers my Questions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try adding this just before the closing head tag ...

```
<style type="text/css">
    #container0, #container1 {
        float: left;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with what you've got there, but your divs have no styling and are not positioned.

I'd suggest positioning them absolute, give them each a top/left, and maybe a border, and you will see something a little more useful.